# ZMQ::LibZMQ3 and strawberry perl

Tags: windows, perl, zeromq, cpan, strawberry-perl

I am trying to install ZMQ::LibZMQ3 on strawberry perl but get the below error message while installing this module also my zmq libs and includes are found under C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 3.2.2 :

```
cpan> install ZMQ::LibZMQ3

Running install for module 'ZMQ::LibZMQ3'
Running make for D/DM/DMAKI/ZMQ-LibZMQ3-1.09.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\D\DM\DMAKI\ZMQ-LibZMQ3-1.09.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\strawberry\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

  CPAN.pm: Building D/DM/DMAKI/ZMQ-LibZMQ3-1.09.tar.gz

Cannot determine perl version info from lib/ZMQ/LibZMQ3.pm
Probing environment variables:
Probing libzmq via pkg-config ...
'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 - No libzmq found...
Probing zeromq3 via pkg-config ...
'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 - No zeromq3 found...
Detected the following ZMQ settings:
 + ZMQ_HOME = "C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 3.2.2"
 + ZMQ_H = "C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 3.2.2\include\zmq.h"
 + ZMQ_INCLUDES = "C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 3.2.2\include"
 + ZMQ_LIBS = "C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 3.2.2\lib"
 + ZMQ_TRACE = (null)
Can't link/include C library 'zmq.h', 'zmq', aborting.
Warning: No success on command[C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL]
  DMAKI/ZMQ-LibZMQ3-1.09.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'ZMQ::LibZMQ3'.
Failed during this command:
 DMAKI/ZMQ-LibZMQ3-1.09.tar.gz                : writemakefile NO 'C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Ma
kefile.PL' returned status 512
```

is it possible to install this cpan module on windows and if yes could someone help what could be the problem here ?

Comment: Ha, all your rep for a bounty. ;) Not sure if relevant but it seems to fail on more than just your system: http://code.activestate.com/ppm/ZMQ-LibZMQ3/

Answer (score 4):

I just tried it in my ActiveStatePerl environment.

First I got the same results, but then I renamed my ZMQ installation 
and removed the spaces.

(From `C:\App\ZeroMQ 2.2.0` to `C:\App\ZeroMQ2_2_0`.)

```
+ ZMQ_HOME = C:\App\ZeroMQ2_2_0
+ ZMQ_H = C:\App\ZeroMQ2_2_0\include\zmq.h
+ ZMQ_INCLUDES = C:\App\ZeroMQ2_2_0\include
+ ZMQ_LIBS = C:\App\ZeroMQ2_2_0\lib
+ ZMQ_TRACE = (null)
```

So I passed the problem

```
Can't link/include C library 'zmq.h', 'zmq', aborting.
```

and got the next step in Makefile.PL

```
Detecting zmq version...
```

(That fails on my system because I have a 0mq 2.2.0 and the perl-binding requires 3.3)

Hope that works for you, too.

Comment: Hmm, may be I should add some obvious facts, too. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Strawberry Perl or ActiveState Perl? Active State Perl can have issues with installing from CPAN unless you've got `nmake` and installed the MinGW utilities. I'm concerned about this:

```
Probing libzmq via pkg-config ...
'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

That raises big hurking red flags for me. I also noticed this little ditty when I tried to install:

```
Detected the following ZMQ settings:
 + ZMQ_HOME = (null)
 + ZMQ_H = (null)
 + ZMQ_INCLUDES = (null)
 + ZMQ_LIBS = (null)
 + ZMQ_TRACE = (null)
```

Hmm.. I have to set these environment variables first.

Next, I got Can't link/include C library 'zmq', aborting. which is from the `assert` in the Makefile. I found this issue on [Github](https://github.com/lestrrat/ZeroMQ-Perl/issues/15). It said:

> Ahhh nice pointer. pthread_create problem. My perl was compiled with thread support. I have recompiled perl and that problem has gone away.

Um yes, Strawberry Perl is compiled with thread support. And, I'm not recompiling it.

What I do recommend is the following:

- Install ZMQ in a directory without spaces in the name. I installed it directly under `C:\ZeroMQ-3.2.2`.
- Define those environment variables. I looked at the Makefile.PL and it requires `ZMQ_LIBS` and `ZMQ_INCLUDES`.
- Make sure you're only using Strawberry Perl and not ActiveState. You can use ActiveState, but it takes a bit of tweaking for something like this.
- Add that Debug flag `debug => 1` in the Makefile.PL (which means you have to do the manual method of the Makefile install where you run `perl Makefile.PL` from the command line.

I'm not going to download and recompile Perl without the threads support to see if this will work. I hope I've sent you on the correct path though.

Answer (score 2):

This package would not install on my ActiveState Perl Windows-based machine - although some of the ZMQ packages will.  It seems support under Windows/Perl is limited at best.

See this page:  https://github.com/lestrrat/p5-ZMQ/issues/14
As there does appear to be known issues with Strawberry Perl.

Hate to add this (don't like Python), but it does seem to work under Windows with Python 2.7.  Just did a quick install and ran the included tests, which passed.  Docs also say Java works well with under Windows as well.

If your not 64-bit this may help (from laufeyjarson):

```
A work-around is to change $^I to have a backup. I used ~ like gvim does:

Line 100 of Makefile.PL:
local $^I = '~';
EDIT:  On recent versions, it is line 203 - JimB

That lets the Makefile.PL work.
```